# Read req.body whether multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded entype form?

Tags: node.js, forms, next.js, body-parser, multer-s3

I'm building a form backend like Formspree on NextJS, so I need to be able to receive all form POSTs at the same endpoint, without being able to control what the forms `enctype` is set as. I need to be able to read the req.body no matter the enctype, and if it's a multipart form then I need to get the files that are attached to the request too.

Currently I do this by running the request though both multer and bodyparser everytime like so:

```
    // Middleware helper
    const runMiddleware = (req, res, fn) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fn(req, res, (result) => {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
          return reject(result);
        }
        return resolve(result);
      });
    });

    handler.post(async (req, res) => {
      const fileUploadAllowed = // business logic
      if (fileUploadAllowed) {
        // Parse req.files
        await runMiddleware(
          req,
          res,
          multer({
            limits: { fileSize: MAX_FILE_SIZE },
            storage: multerS3({
              s3,
              bucket: process.env.FILE_SERVER_BUCKET,
              acl: 'public-read',
              key(_, file, cb) {
                cb(null, `${user._id}/${form._id}/${submissionId}/${file.originalname}`);
              },
            }),
          }).array('_file', 5),
        );
      }
      // Parse the req.body
      await runMiddleware(
        req,
        res,
        bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
      );
      await runMiddleware(
        req,
        res,
        bodyParser.json(),
      );
      
      // Access here
      console.log(req.files, req.body);
    });
```

This setup works if the forms enctype is `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but the problem is if the `fileUploadAllowed` is false then the req never runs through Multer, and if the form is multipart then the body will be empty too and the whole POST is rejected. I can't just run it through Multer no matter what because the files are automatically uploaded to my S3 bucket.

What is the best way to handle this setup?